# Updating time of postgres indexes

Tags: postgresql, database-indexes

I was wondering about the performance of indexes in PostgreSQL. I was mining in the web articles trying to figure out how to check the updating time of an index. I thought Postgres could have some direct construct. The scenario is: there are 4 semesters of sales periodically inserted into a table which has an index on the pk column; I would take the time for updating that index in each semester.

Comment: There is no "INDEX UPDATE" process in the databases. Because the indexes will be updated automatically during the inserting or updating. Maybe you can do reindex for all tables for example one time during the year.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to get the time of indexes' automatic update?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are always updated automatically, right when you modify the data. There is nothing extra you have to do, and there is nothing you can do to influence that process (for example, suspend index maintenance and do it later).

To preempt comments that criticize “there is nothing you can do to influence that process”: yes, GIN indexes have a “pending list”, whose existence and size you can configure.

Comment: I don't want to interfere with the automatic update, I just want to know the time passed for it.

Comment: I see. The only way to figure that out is to do it with and without the index and measure the difference. But that difference will be substantial.

Comment: I had thoughts about this solution. It's pretty strange there's no direct command for this. Indexes' use should be evaluated even from this perspective. Anyway, I've appreciated your time and your answers.